# Updating a value in one row where is currently null ,where in other row there is data

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm working to reconsile or AWS bill in our cost reporting  tool we're built and I need some guidence on how to execute this type of update in Postgres.

The AWS bill is in the Table 'BillingData' and every row is the cost billing per 'ResourceId' every hour.

For example, we have

```
ResourceId|BlendedCost|user:Product|UsageStartDate
i-34r8uefg | 0.8763 |<null>|04-01-01 01:00
i-34r8uefg | 0.8763 |AwesomeProductTag|04-01-01 02:00
```

This shows that at hour 01 the instance was not tagged, but on hour 02 it was. We have 1,000s of rows like this.

What I would like to do is wherever there's  a row that has  NULL data for column "user:Product", populate that column with data that is elsewhere in that table, for the same "ResourceId".

In more clear terms, someone when they created 'i-34r8uefg' did not tag it properly, but did so later on. I have the following query which gives me rows where instances are not tagged at one hour, but tagged at a different hour

```
select   "ResourceId","user:Product" from billingdata
where "user:Product" NOTNULL
and "ResourceId" in
(select DISTINCT "ResourceId"
from billingdata
where "user:Product" ISNULL);
```

I want to set the `"user:Product"` where it is null at one hour(row), to the value that exists later on in the table.

Comment: Your request is not clear.. could you provide a clearer example of what you trying to do

Comment: let's say 10 rows have `null` and 2 rows have non-null values for a resourceId..what should you do in that case?

Comment: @vkp what i want to do is make where it is `null` to the value of the data where it is not null.

Comment: @asmgx i have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your requirements are:

1. Two rows must have the same `ResourceId`
2. The target row must have a null `user:Product`
3. The source tow must have a non-null `user:Product`
4. The source row must be entered after the target row

...then you can use this:

```
UPDATE "BillingData" AS "Target" SET
    "user:Product" = "Source"."user:Product"
FROM "BillingData" AS "Source"
WHERE "Source"."ResourceId" = "Target"."ResourceId"
AND "Target"."user:Product" IS NULL
AND "Source"."user:Product" IS NOT NULL
AND "Target"."UsageStartDate" < "Source"."UsageStartDate"
;
```

Note that if you have two source rows with the same `ResourceId` but different non-null `user:Product` values then it will be a crapshoot as to which row is used as the source for the update.  You should check the uniqueness of source rows beforehand using a query like this:

```
SELECT
    "ResourceId"
FROM "BillingData"
WHERE "user:Product" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY "ResourceId"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

...or alternately, use this as a filter predicate in your query to avoid the problem (but not fully solve your original problem), like so:

```
UPDATE "BillingData" AS "Target" SET
    "user:Product" = "Source"."user:Product"
FROM "BillingData" AS "Source"
WHERE "Source"."ResourceId" = "Target"."ResourceId"
AND "Target"."user:Product" IS NULL
AND "Source"."user:Product" IS NOT NULL
AND "Target"."UsageStartDate" < "Source"."UsageStartDate"
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM "BillingData"
    WHERE "user:Product" IS NOT NULL
    AND "ResourceId" = "Source"."ResourceId"
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
;
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly it. Thank you.